# Is it safe to commit compiled.php file for Laravel?

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I understand that the Laravel developers have ignored it in their .gitignore file, but they also ignored the composer.lock file which I think is bad form. My question is it safe to commit and push that compiled.php to production?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your deployment process and of what you include in the `compiled.php` file. **If you add `composer.lock` in your version manager, only run `composer install` when you deploy and add nothing in  `config/compile.php`, yes it is quite safe.**

But what is the gain ? You just have to put this in `composer.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
```

And the `compiled.php` file will be generated in each deployment. Like that you will avoid any kind of problem if anybody in the project decide to run a `composer update` somewhere.

As a package manager, composer help you managing you dependencies. If you commit your compiled.php file, you completely bypass composer and use `compiled.php` as a very rustic package manager...

Comment: Plus 1 for the post install/update scripts. Didn't realize that was possible :). As for the question of why, it's 15 seconds or so out of the deployment process (and 1 less thing that can go wrong).